# Auto refresh GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a requirement to reload the groovy server page for every 30 secs with new data from webservice. I tried using "http-equiv" header, with this header some data is not reloading properly and controller is not hitting when page is reloaded.

Comment: http://grails.asia/grails-example-application-simple-ajax-chat here is an example doing what Dónal suggest below - I would then compare something like this with websockets. I went down this route initially for chat based system and ended up using websockets take a look at the jssh plugin for websockets updating gsp or wschat or boselecta plugins

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this one help you

$(document).ready(

```
        function() {
            setInterval(function() { 
            $('#divId').load('/app/controller/action');
            }, 5000);
        });
```

Comment: Since my action in controller is rendering view,i am not able to use this solution and in my action i was using threads to make parallel Webservice call ,after fixing thread code now i am able to refresh the page with http-equiv="refresh" without any missing information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some JavaScript e.g. [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to refresh the page every 30 seconds.